# HP Intelligent provisioning (An error occurred while installing the system) Land is not defined

Tags: installation, operating-systems

I'm trying to install OS through a network interface. I'm also launching the console and mounting the shape. Then I'm doing all steps, but finally I see the message "ReferenceError:Land is not defined busy.htm:343"

Installation was tested on different images of systems.

Maybe somebody faced with the problem and can help?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Problem and reinstalled the intelligent provisioning Firmware - then it worked. (HP ProLiant ML350 G9)
In fact I downgraded to Vers 2.4 first and t

Comment: Part of your answer is missing. It ends with "first and t" ...